# Can't deploy SRV in Elite: Dangerous

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm trying to deploy a Surface Recon Vehicle (SRV) in Elite: Dangerous (with the Horizons DLC), but the option to **Deploy** the SRV in red / greyed out, so I can't select it.

**Question**: How do I deploy the SRV?

Answer (score 5):

If you ever encounter non-functional systems in Elite: Dangerous, there's a very good possibility that you've disabled one of your ship's modules, and simply forgotten about it. It happens to me on a regular basis.

Thankfully, this is an easy thing to check:

1. In your ship, visit the **Systems Panel**, on the right (<kbd>4</kbd> by default)
2. Use the <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> keys to navigate to **Modules**
3. Select your **Planetary Vehicle Hangar** from the list of modules
4. **Activate** the module
5. Go back to the **Role Panel** (the bottom one) and try to the SRV again

If this doesn't work, make sure you have a SRV in the Planetary Vehicle Hangar (PVH). If you destroyed your SRV, you might need to purchase a new one. Some PVH's hold more than one SRV, for backup purposes.

Comment: Also make sure you are landed

Answer (score 2):

It's also worth making sure you have an SRV equipped in your vehicle hangar, as they aren't automatically purchased along with a vehicle hangar.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to deploy your **Landing Gear** as it's possible to land with it up & there are no warnng sounds. This prevents the **SRV** deploying (lowering the LG while on the ground landed also allows you to deploy).

Answer (score 0):

When you land make sure it says secured ship.

Some places you can land, but the ship wont be secured to the ground, if that's the case then it cannot be deployed.

In most case just move the ships around abit in the area, until the HUD no longer says the terrain is unsuitable for landing.

Answer (score 0):

0) Buy and equip the SRV hangar module, and buy at least one SRV for it

1) Fly to a landable planet (they have the blue crescent over them in the system view)

2) Enter orbital cruise, then fly down til you hit orbital glide.

3) After exiting orbital glide, fly down to the surface of the planet.

4) Deploy landing gear.

5) Find a flat spot to land on (your landing HUD will turn on and help you as you get close to the surface).

6) After landing, activate the SRV/fighter panel (default mapping is "3").

7) Select the option to deploy the SRV and enjoy driving around.

Answer (score 0):

When your ship is over terrain that you can land on it will highlight as yellow / gold. I flew around slowly in expanding circles until my ship did a yellow 'blip' and then strafed backwards until finding that spot. Once I found that spot I came straight down and landed, secured, and was able to launch the SRV.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, specifically after a multicrew session. To fix it, I landed anywhere on the planet, then hit ESC and went to Menu. Then, relogged back in. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Also make sure that your Planetary Vehicle Hanger is powered under the Modules tab -- if you don't, the option to deploy will be greyed out.